# Urdu message sent from C# Rich TextBox to mobile handset, is in unreadable format Using AT command

Tags: c#, sms, richtextbox, gsm, at-command

I am using `AT command` in C# 4.5 to send SMS to mobile device, message sent in `english` is readable in mobile but message sent in `other than english language` is not readable, it just shows `"??????????????"` in mobile i don't know how to solve this. I googled a lot but couldn't get any satisfactory answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the relevant code you have to this question.

Comment: Did you fixed your problem?